# Cannot configure/build memkeys (a memcached activity app)

Tags: memcached, configure, autoconf

There's a project that lets you snoop on memcached activity via pcap, and display the results in `top`/`htop` manner.

https://github.com/tumblr/memkeys.git

To build, you need `autoconf` and `automake`, and you configure the program for your system by running the supplied `autogen.sh` script.

When I run this, after a couple of dozen lines, it dies with the following output:

```
...
checking for g++44... no
checking for g++... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/data/tmp/memkeys/memkeys-master':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

The `config.log` file indicates that `Configure` generated a C program with an error (I have gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3) installed):

```
configure:3191: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "memkeys"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "memkeys"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.1"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "memkeys 0.1"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "bmatheny@mobocracy.net"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "memkeys"
| #define VERSION "0.1"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
|
| int
| main ()
| {
|
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
```

It looks like a statement was meant to be generated before the `return` statement, but nothing was inserted and the source is left with a lone semi-colon.

Does this ring a bell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for archeologists who stumble across this problem in the future, the answer is that the server in question wasn't entirely set up for development (and `Configure` wasn't able to identify the problem correctly).

```
apt-get install build-essential
```

was the missing piece. If you want to deploy the resulting dynamic binary across a series of Ubuntu hosts, you'll also need to ensure that the `libpcrecpp0` package is installed on them.